# Alternatives to Scaffold-DbContext for generating entity types

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I'm trying to make an ASP.NET Core application that uses LINQ-to-SQL and, preferably, uses a tool to generate the classes. I've followed the steps of different tutorials like https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-using-Entity-1464feea and whenever I run `Scaffold-DbContext` I get a data context generated but no entities. Instead I get the error

```
    // Unable to generate entity type for table 'dbo.MyTable'. Please see the warning messages.
```

for every one of my tables. There's nothing "weird" about my database, and the warning messages don't exist. Therefore I'm wondering if there's an alternative way to generate the entities.

Comment: Does your tables have primary keys? This is required

Comment: @ErikEJ That fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: So *There's nothing "weird" about my database*, but your tables don't have a primary key?  Hmm.  I'm having trouble reconciling those two things.

Answer (score 1):

Scaffold-DbContext requires your tables to have primary keys!